# Using Personal data before consent

Tags: internet, software, privacy, gdpr, consent

I am having an Android App which is going to use some services such as Google Analytics, Firebase etc.

I have a thought of having two different consent screens for different region user such as EU Users will have a screen in which the checkbox will be unchecked by default whereas users from other region will have the checkbox prechecked.

I would be using the GPS location before taking the consent to find out the users region(Location may not be exact location).

Now my question I will use the GPS location to only check the location and WILL NOT STORE IT OR COLLECT IT AT ANY COST.

Does the GDPR or any other privacy law stop or disallow me to do that?

Any help will be really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this is OK according to the GDPR and other European laws.

The relevant bit is GDPRs rules for [Lawfulness of processing](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-6-gdpr/), and in particular Article 6 (1)b, which says that it is legal to do this if

> processing is necessary for the performance of a contract to which the data subject is party or in order to take steps at the request of the data subject prior to entering into a contract;

In your particular case, signing up for using your app is "entering into a contract" and it is the data subject who has requested to use your app that is subject to this processing.

Comment: Just one more question is this permitted by other country's privacy law?

Comment: I am in the Europe. I don't know about the law in every jurisdiction on the planet, but AFAIK, the EU is the only jurisdiction that go to great lengths regulate lawfulness of processing and consent.